# In BrE, do you say that you study in a programme or on a programme?

Tags: prepositions

When I google "study **in** a programme" on UK pages I only get one single hit, whereas when I google "study **on** a programme" I get almost 50 hits. However, when I check the same phrases on [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=study%20in%20a%20programme%2Cstudy%20on%20a%20programme&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), the version with "in" is clearly more frequent. This may be because there are no hits on NGrams for BrE, but still – I'm still wondering which version is actually the preferred one in "proper" (i.e. not colloquial) BrE.

Comment: What is the full sentence you want to say.  Normally you would just say "I study maths" and not "I study on a programme of maths"

Comment: e.g., "If you study on/in a teacher training programme..."; "Those studying on/in one of the music programmes..."; "Students on/in this programme..." and so on.

Comment: Neither.  Usually in the UK we'd say we are studying a subject, such as maths, computing, English or whatever.

Comment: Indeed  "If you are training to be a teacher..." "Those studying music..."   "Students on this course"...  I'm not saying that "programme" is never used, but it isn't the first word I'd use in those contexts.

Comment: @JamesK - actually there are [zero hits in google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=study+in+a+programme%2Cstudy+on+a+programme&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) in British English for either of these examples.  So for these particular examples "never" is a distinct possibility.

Comment: In Ngrams, do you see the drop-down menu that says "English (2019)"? You can use that to select BrE-only corpuses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We would normally say someone is '*in* a programme', for example:

> He is in a rehabilitation programme.

However, it isn't usual to refer to education that way. A 'programme of study' in British English means the curriculum - the planned topics and material that a student would cover. These can frequently change. As a British English speaker, if someone were to say to me "I'm in a study programme" it would sound so unidiomatic that I would imagine they meant some special kind of programme outside of standard education.

In British English we normally refer to being in the various stages of education this way:

- I'm at school ('in' is more American)
- I'm in college ('at' is common too, though)
- I'm on a course (either a college course or any other kind of study, such as a vocational study or a training programme)
- I'm at university

Comment: Thank you - this is really helpful! :)